# Sharepoint call external web service real time

Tags: workflow, web-services, api

i am using sharepoint workflow 2013 to call external web service from external web site.
How to i set real time connection between external web service and sharepoint?
In the other words , i want to workflow called automatically when external web service items are added or updated and just call one item that added or updated.
Thanks a lot
Amin Hadi

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? And specifically which platform/external website you are trying to connect with SharePoint Workflow? Is it one of the Microsoft product or something else?

Comment: Im using sharepoint server 2013 and external website is php.